# DecimalFormat pattern for not prefixing zero before decimal

Tags: java

I am stuck with a problem in writing a method for parsing a float number. Basically I have a method to which string value of a float will be passed. 
I want to format it in such a way that if '.12' is passed to it, it should not pre-append '0' before the decimal.
And if I pass '0.12' to it, it should not remove the first '0' and the number should remain as is.

Whatever I do, '0' is always getting prefixed before decimal.

The method that I have written is:

```
public static Number parseNumber(String value) throws ParseException {
    NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
    ((DecimalFormat) numberFormatter).setParseBigDecimal(true);

    String displayFormatCode = "###,###,###.##";

    ((DecimalFormat) numberFormatter).applyPattern(displayFormatCode);
    return numberFormatter.parse(value);
}
```

Here the constraint is that I cannot set additional code to check regex. Since this method can be used for other data types as well and the `displayFormatCode` being used in the above method is a variable externally set, I need to figure out the proper format code.

I have searched several forums, but the only solution I got was using regex which is not an option here.

Comment: you need to return the `format`'d value - you are returning a `Number`

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. `.12` and `0.12` is just the same number mathematically as well as as a `double`.

Comment: Right, but this is something that came from the client. So can't help it. Client is GOD! Basically I want to achieve '.12'.

Comment: The `parse` method does not format a number, but as its name implies it parses a string into a number.

Comment: Yes, but which other API should I use then

Comment: Some clients can be educated when they require stupid things.

Comment: Can you return `String` instead of `Number`?

Comment: Why is using a regex not an option?

Comment: @Henry: Absolutely...

Comment: @MauricePerry: We have this method as a generic one for other data types as well, I have removed extra code to pin point the problem. And the displayFormatCode local variable that you see here is actually not a local variable but is set externally based on the data type. It would be a bad practice to put regex handling in this generic method.

Comment: @ahoxha: Yep, it can be done.

Comment: @ahoxha what do you have in mind? What's the method doing then with the passed in string? Nothing and just returning it?

Comment: My question is: what are the possible values of the `value` parameter? Do you ever receive `0.12567` that you have to format it to `0.13'?

Comment: @ahoxha If 0.12567 is received it wont get formatted to 0.13. However, if '121,122.125454' is received, it will get formatted to '121122.125454'

Comment: I'm really confused now. What I see now has more to do with parsing an already formatted string into a number rather than formatting a number. If all you have to do is remove the thousands separator, then just do a `value.replace(",","")`.

Comment: @ahoxha Well the application is i18n enabled. Like in Germany, ',' is used instead of decimal point. So, replacing comma ain't an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code because it's running OK in my environment

```
public static String formatAmountTwoDecimal(Double amount) {
    if (amount == null) {
        return "0.0";
    } 
    else {
        String amt = Formatter.formatDouble(amount);
        return amt;
    }
}

public static String formatDouble(Double param){
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    String retVal=null;
    if(param!=null){
        retVal=decimalFormat.format(param);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

This answer contains Java code, therefore, I couldn't answer as comments!

Hope you will get your desired answer!

Comment: Thanks mate. But this code approximates the value up to 2 places of decimal which is not desired. And if I replace '0's in the display format code with '#', 0 starts getting prefixed again.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to achieve is to remove the '0' before the decimal sign, 
you can convert the Number to a String, and strip the first character if it's 0.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Number value = parseNumber(".512");
    System.out.println(removeLeadingZero(value));
}

public static String removeLeadingZero(Number value) {
    String tempValue = value.toString();
    if (tempValue.charAt(0) == '0') {
        tempValue = tempValue.substring(1);
    }
    return tempValue;
}
```

This outputs `.512`, and won't interfere with your existing setup.